# setting UISwipeGesture sensitivity levels

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, uigesturerecognizer, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I have a little problem with UISwipeGestures. I would want to implement three levels of swiping. That is a short(quick) swipe, medium(relatively slower) and long(slow) swipe. Each triggering different actions and animations. What I have done so far is the usual swipe implementation below.

```
 oneFingerSwipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                                 initWithTarget:self
                                                 action:@selector(swipeToLeft:)];
[oneFingerSwipeLeft setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] addGestureRecognizer:oneFingerSwipeLeft];




//handle right swipes
oneFingerSwipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                                  initWithTarget:self
                                                  action:@selector(swipeToRight:)];
[oneFingerSwipeRight setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] addGestureRecognizer:oneFingerSwipeRight];


-(void) swipeToLeft:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    hasSwipedToLeft = true;
    //perform an action
}
-(void) swipeToRight:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    hasSwipedToRight = true;
    //perform an action
}
```

What modifications can I make to my code to take care of the 3 levels of swipe sensitivity stated above.

Comment: you'd have to create a custom gesture recognizer

Comment: Did you make any discovery? Can you please share it if so.